# Has anyone successfully used react-testing-library to test change events on a draftJS Editor component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, draftjs, react-testing-library

​The `fireEvent.change()` just doesn't work.

It says there are no setters on the element.

I tried using aria selectors instead

```
const DraftEditor = getByRole('textbox')
DraftEditor.value ='something';
fireEvent.change(DraftEditor);
```

I tried same again using query selector

```
const DraftEditor = container.querySelector('.public-DraftEditor-content'));
```

Tried keyboard events instead.

Nothing.

Has anyone managed to text a rich text input with draftjs and react testing library?

Comment: Any new on this?

Comment: Nope. I gave up and ended up using cypress to do the test instead.

Comment: yeah so do I :)

Comment: A longer discussion on ways around this has been fleshed out [on spectrum here](https://spectrum.chat/testing-library/help/has-anyone-successfully-used-rtl-to-test-change-events-on-a-draftjs-text-box~f1928053-9e53-407a-9be5-70babeb4b692)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to do it by getting inspiration from some issue description for [draft-js](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/325#issuecomment-344091458) and adapting that to our case at hand

```
import { createEvent } from "@testing-library/dom"
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react"
```

---

```
function createPasteEvent(html) {
  const text = html.replace('<[^>]*>', '');
  return {
    clipboardData: {
      types: ['text/plain', 'text/html'],
      getData: (type) => (type === 'text/plain' ? text : html),
    },
  };
}
```

---

```
renderedComponent = render(<App />)
const editorNode = renderedComponent.querySelector(".public-DraftEditor-content")
const eventProperties = createPasteEvent(textToPaste)
const pasteEvent = createEvent.paste(editorNode, eventProperties)
pasteEvent.clipboardData = eventProperties.clipboardData
fireEvent(editorNode, pasteEvent)
```

Some additional notes:

- renderedComponent in my case is the parent element in which the Editor component is rendered.
- apparently, 'ClipboardEvent' is not implemented in JSDOM (see [list of supported events](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/tree/d6f8a97b5fb7709d6ad0215c1ae95fd4cab58489/lib/jsdom/living/events)), therefore, the call to createEvent.paste creates a generic Event, and not a ClipboardEvent. As a workaround, I copy the necessary clipboardData properties again to the generated generic event so that they will be taken into account by the function [editOnPaste](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/ed09f78c3ddf6d32c381555e7164076a62a7994f/src/component/handlers/edit/editOnPaste.js) of the Draft-js editor, which itself will be triggered because of the fired event.

Comment: this worked well, but it breaks on latest testing-library/dom version

as pastEvent is readonly

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini is right, but it seems the offending line (`pasteEvent.clipboardData = ...`) is not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working mocking the editor and intercepting the `onChange` method so you can still execute all the lib functions:

```
const draftjs = require('draft-js');

draftjs.Editor = jest.fn(props => {
  const modifiedOnchange = e => {
    const text = e.target.value;
    const content = ContentState.createFromText(text);
    props.onChange(EditorState.createWithContent(content));
  };
  return <input className="editor" onChange={e => modifiedOnchange(e)} />;
});
```

Comment: I am really looking for a solution like this, but I couldn't find a way to mock it myself. Tried your answer but is says `ContentState is not defined`

Comment: You have to import Content state class from draft js